# .NET PropertyGrid: Create Expandable item when value is null

Tags: c#, class, null, propertygrid, expandable

I have class (ClassA) with some public properties. One of the properties (ClassBValue) is of a class type (ClassB) which has some public properties, too. Now I want to show ClassA objects in a PropertyGrid. 
I use the

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
```

Attribute for the ClassB property of ClassA.

The problem is, that the ClassBValue property is `null` when it is shown in the PropertyGrid. How can I enable the user to create a ClassB object within the PropertyGrid?
The user should be able to set a value for the ClassBValue and edit the sub-properties and also to delete the value (set it to null).

Answer (score 1):

You would need a custom type converter for that.

Comment: I already tried to implement a type converter inherited from ExpandableObjectConverter that converts from/to string. But then the user has to enter a string in the correct format to create ClassB object value. That is not intuitive and ergonomic.
Any hints for doing it better?